# Can access hadoop fs through shell, but not through java main

Tags: java, hadoop

I would like to see the following code make a directory in my "/tmp" via hdfs.
I can, for instance, run

```
hadoop fs -mkdir hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/newdir
```

and succeed.

jps lists that namenode, datanode are running.
Hadoop version 0.20.1+169.89.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://localhost:9000");
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    fs.mkdirs(new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/alex"));
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException; Host Details : local host is: "<my-machine-name>/192.168.2.6"; destination host is: "localhost":9000; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1351)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:2394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:2365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$16.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:817)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$16.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:813)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirsInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:813)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirs(DistributedFileSystem.java:806)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:1933)
    at com.twitter.amplify.core.dao.AccessHdfs.main(AccessHdfs.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveRpcResponse(Client.java:995)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:891)
```

Comment: FWIW, that first line which is being cut off says
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException; Host Details : local host is: "<my-machine-name>/192.168.2.6"; destination host is: "localhost":9000;

Comment: Potentially a version mismatch between your client and server library versions - can your confirm the versions match?

Comment: How should I go about checking those?

Comment: How are you launching your java job? Can you include the full command line used, and are you using the standard Driver pattern (`extends Configured implements Tool` for your main class)

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ to run. The command is too long to post here, since the classpath is so big, but here is the command sans classpath:
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7534 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 12.app/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain my.package.name.AccessHdfs

I'm not familiar with the Driver pattern. Is this something that I should be using? I can look into it while I await your response. Thanks again, Chris.

Comment: Can you share more information - what version of hadoop do you have on your classpath? How are you launching the job in IntelliJ - If you bundle up your classes into a jar and run via the command line (`hadoo pjar myJar.jar MainClass`) does it work?

Comment: I am launching the job by pressing "run"

Here are my classpath hadoop jars from intellij:
org.apache.hadoop-hadoop-auth-2.2.0.jar

org.apache.hadoop-hadoop-hdfs-2.2.0.jar

org.apache.hadoop-hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar 

org.apache.hadoop-hadoop-annotations-2.2.0.jar

It does work if I run hadoop jar from commandline!
Maybe it's what you were saying about different versions of hadoop? I mean hadoop version isn't the same as those libraries... Any further thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a version mismatch - your questions notes a NameNode running version 0.20.1+169.89 (which i think is from Cloudera distro CDH2 - http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/2/), and in IntelliJ you are using Apache hadoop version 2.2.0.

Update your IntelliJ classpath to use the jars compatible with your cluster version - namely:

- `hadoop-0.20.1+169.89-core.jar`

Answer (score 0):

I had same version of Hadoop(hadoop-2.2.0) installed on my master and slave nodes but still I was getting same exception. To get rid of it I have followed below steps:
1. from $HADOP_HOME execute sbin/stop-all.sh, to stop the cluster
2. delete the data directory from all problematic node. If you dont know where data directory is then open core-site.xml, find the value corresponding to hadoop.tmp.dir, go to that directory, then cd dfs there you will find a directory named data, delete that data directory from all problematic datanodes
3. format the master node
4. from $HADOP_HOME execute sbin/start-all.sh, to start the cluster